# How to trace Stack Frame manually with just raw program memory record?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, stack-frame

I have a memory dump of a program, and I am aware of the range of the stack memory. My question revolves around identifying the stack frame within this chunk of memory. In simpler terms, how can I pinpoint the portion of memory where the return address, which is pushed onto the stack after a 'call' instruction, is stored?

I came across an [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/unwinding-stack-frame-pointers-and-orc),which recommends using Frame Pointer Unwinds. It explains that at the start of a stack frame, the return address is pushed, followed by the frame pointer. The frame pointer points to a memory address in the previous stack frame, which, in turn, contains the memory address of the even earlier one, and so on. By tracing these addresses, one can navigate through all the stack frames. However, despite analyzing my dump data, I have been unable to establish this chain of memory.

I'm seeking advice or techniques from anyone who might have a solution to this issue. Can anyone offer hints or methods to help me with this problem?

Note that I can not use CaptureStackBackTrace, I just can check the expected executable status of a memory page. I am working on window system x86-64.

I've been trying to read numerous online resources and analyzing data from memory dumps, but I don't know which approach to use to determine the stack frame

Comment: This varies greatly by platform, but you're specifically talking about Linux x64?

Comment: Frame pointers are optional and mostly not used in optimized code.

Comment: Yes, that why I can not trace the frame pointer in the morden program. 
In this case, do I have any hints to trace the stack frame?

Comment: You need to study the function where the dump was taken to find the return address location. Then repeat with the caller. Heuristically, you can just start looking at the stack contents one by one, and see if any point past a `call` instruction that might have jumped to the current function.